# How to pass parameters in Akka Stream Flow from a previous stage?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm playing with Akka Streams and curious about constructing a `Flow` through a function with parameters. Parameters should be passed from the previous one stream stage.

Let's assume that we have following inputs and outputs:

```scala
case class InitElement(v: Int)

trait StreamResult
case class StageA(v: Int) extends StreamResult
case class StageB(v: Int) extends StreamResult

trait StreamFailure extends StreamResult { val msg: String }
case class StageAFailure(msg: String) extends StreamFailure
case class StageBFailure(msg: String) extends StreamFailure
```

Stream stages for them look like:

```scala
val stageA = Flow[InitElement].map {
    init => 
      if (init.v > 10) 
        StageA(init.v) 
      else 
        StageAFailure(s"${init.v} less than 10")
  }

  def stageB(input: StreamResult)(externalService: Set[Int]) = Flow[StreamResult].map {
    case failure: StreamFailure => failure
    case StageA(v) => 
      if (externalService.contains(v)) 
        StageB(v)
      else
        StageBFailure(s"$v is absent in external service")
  }

  val graph = Source.single(InitElement(12))
    .via(stageA)
//How can I pass output of previous stage into 'stageB' function?
    .via(stageB(_)(Set(11, 15, 20)))
    .toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right)
```

I don't see any way to pass result of `stageA` into the function which constructs the next stage.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `stageB` builds a `Flow[StreamResult, StreamResult, _]`. It doesn't need to take `(input: StreamResult)` as a parameter. Note that you don't use `input` anywhere in `stageB` definition. The element comes from the `Flow[StreamResult]` on which you will `map`.

This should be enough:

```
def stageB(externalService: Set[Int]) = … // As you wrote it

val graph = Source.single(InitElement(12))
  .via(stageA)
  .via(stageB(Set(11, 15, 20)))
  .toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right)
```

Comment: I knew it (that the answer will be on top)! Thanks!